# JSON Object Help

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
{
  "accuracy": 0.17,
  "dogr": 108,
  "dogt": 22,
  "elo0": 602.29,
  "elo1": 587.28,
  "games": 305
}
```

I have those values above from JSON Object,

```
    JObject general = (JObject)bfbc_array[0]["general"];
    foreach (float generalsNumbers in general.PropertyValues())
    {
        listBox7.Items.Add(generalsNumbers);
    }
```

That loop iterates through the object and I can retrieve the number of each one. Which is perfect, however I want to retrieve the text as well and I'm completely stumped. What do I need to use so that I can get the text as well? (I am using JSON.NET)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to loop over `general` as follows:

```
JObject general = (JObject)bfbc_array[0]["general"];
foreach (var item in general)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

If you need the numbers to be of type `float` you can cast them:

```
float value = (float)item.Value;
```

Comment: Be sure to cast the array over to a `(JOBject)` to allow the item to contain the Key Value pairs.